# Free Solap client for geomondrian

Tags: openlayers, pentaho, geospatial, mondrian, geokettle

Jpivot hasn't been updated since 2008, it doesn't allow the visualization of geo spatial properties within a map, is there a free alternative that allow it for geomondrian ?